# Are more and more questions dismissed, answers downvoted unnecessarily?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, asking-questions

Now, with the addition of so many sister sites, SO is becoming more and more difficult to actually ask a relevant question. I can't get an answer or discussion on anything anymore:

1. More and more questions are being dismissed as "off-topic", because the reviewers may or may not accurately think they belong on a sister site.
2. Each site has site-specific policies which are stringently adhered to by reviewers.
3. Site participants readily downvote questions from new users with disparaging comments about why the question doesn't fit the forum.

It's getting to the point where I don't want to ask a question about anything anymore, because I will get downvoted for not following the rules of engagement.

When I'm researching questions on SO, I see many users getting downvoted who either provided legitimate answers or somebody just didn't like what they had to say or how they said it. I upvote a majority of these responses.

Each time I've posted on a sister site (aside from Ask Ubuntu), my question has been deleted as "off-topic".

I've been using SO for years. How will this encourage any kind of community when there is a prevailing sense of strict control over content? So what if you ask an Apache configuration on SO instead of Server Fault or a programming question on Code Review?

So can we relax a bit and just let people have some dialogue? How can we influence folks to relax and let an organic process happen?

Comment: case in point. I posted this and immediately saw 2 downvotes. How can you donwvote something you haven't even had time to read?

Comment: Because it's been asked and answered many times.  How can we influence folks to search before asking?

Comment: Because people see "answers downvoted unnecessarily" in the title and stop reading?

Comment: But does that remove the legitimacy of the question? I mean, it's been up for 6 minutes with 6 downvotes. The question may have been asked but, has anything changed? Why not implement restrictions or relax posting guidelines? There is no dialog, just trolling at this point.

Comment: *"...because I will get downvoted for not following the rules"*....erm, yep...what's your point?

Comment: "I see many users get downvoted who either provided legitimate answers or somebody just didn't like what they had to say or how they said it. I upvote a majority of these responses." So you're sympathy-upvoting posts based on what you *imagine* other people's downvote reasons to be?

Comment: Re: "I can't get an answer or discussion on anything anymore", the last question you asked on SO was in last August, and the last downvote you had on one of your questions was over a year ago. Your questions seem to be well-received here.

Comment: No. Because, god forbid, this site is infested with trolls who are downvoting legitimate answers.

Comment: @Brad, yeah SO questions are ok. Ask Ubuntu as well. This is more about sister sites.

Comment: @eggmatters so, you're supposed to research your question, right? If it's been asked before, you need to at least MENTION the dupes you found and explain why your question is different. If you don't do it, people will go "yeah that's poorly researched. I won't waste my breath re-explaining this, AGAIN".... honestly it takes about 20 seconds to read your question (and that is taking my sweet time in reading)... so downvotes after a couple seconds IS warranted on your question

Comment: @eggmatters then post on the sister site meta? If it's about a non Stack Overflow site, it should go on the specific meta...

Comment: If you think the sites are that bad, stop using them. Problem solved.

Comment: "There is no dialog, just trolling at this point." The downvotes **are** the dialog. People are saying they *don't want* the changes you propose. Disagreement isn't trolling.

Comment: +1 - I respect what StackOverflow has done for programmers everywhere, but I strongly agree that the imposition of overly strict rules is excessive here.  It alienates amateur and international users and even discourages the usership of veterans.  Personally, I've started following @Yannis 's advice ...  every once in a while, I remember how much SO has done for me and come back to participate, but the increasing closed-mindedness of users always leads me to the same place eventually ...  elsewhere

Comment: @smartcaveman honestly the biggest problem Stack now has is to balance the "being useful to a LOT of people" and "not turning into a help desk" with the sheer SCALE of users... not an easy task, and I don't think the site fully succeeds in this.... but I fail to see how to really improve on it without sacrificing what made stack... well.... stack

Comment: '"I see many users get downvoted who either provided legitimate answers or somebody just didn't like what they had to say or how they said it' - examples please.

Comment: I wish all the users who moan about over-strict rules would set up a helpdesk site of their very own so I could send all the liars, deadbeats etc. their way.

Comment: "let an organic process happen"... Rotting is an organic process, do you really want that?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Life on earth wouldn't exist without rotting as a process, so...yes?

Comment: @Patrice - imagine a world where people saw questions they didn't like and just kinda ignored them.  Today we're in an situation with the opposite extreme - people routinely down-vote questions without reading them.  Here's a query I just wrote counting the downvotes of the top 20 StackOverflow users.  Notice a pattern?  http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/448554/how-many-downvotes-have-been-cast-by-the-top-20-stackoverflow-users  .

Comment: @Servy, that and everything is increasing in entropy and the eventual heat death of the universe, but I was specifically talking about letting an organic process, such as rotting, occur on SO.

Comment: @MartinJames - It sounds like you've taken it upon yourself to solve everyone on the internet's problems and safeguard one of the highest traffic websites from traffic that you personally find offensive.  I can only think of one person who might be at fault for that situation.

Comment: @smartcaveman [FTFY](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/448556)

Comment: @smartcaveman Jon Skeet has cast [4,780 downvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=topactivity), not one.  The only thing your query tells us is that votes are anonymized on data.se, so you can't see how many up/down votes anyone has cast.  And your assertion that people downvote questions without reading them is unsupported - citation needed.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - oh thanks

Comment: @smartcaveman Clearly you're entirely unfamiliar with the site's mission, the story of why it was created, and what its continued goals are.  This is unsurprising, considering that you're making suggestions with the express purpose of preventing those goals from being accomplished.  Rather than trying to turn SO from a site that actually values quality, into a pile of filth, like virtually every other Q/A site out there, why not just move over to one of the other sites that has no problem being a garbage heap?

Comment: @smartcaveman but the goal of stack is to be a good repository for knowledge. Leaving bad questions that have no future value is NOT letting stack stay "stack". Not saying it wouldn't be a solution. Saying I was asking for a scaleable solution where stack would remain what it is. And I kinda like the pattern you were showing me. Because of the error in your query, it now shows a VERY different pattern actually.

Comment: @Servy - you're off-base dude.  For one, I've been a member of the SO community longer than you have.  Secondly - I've referred countless programmers to SO as a valuable resource.  But do you want to know what they say when I refer mentees today?  They are afraid to post on the site because people here are *jerks (no one used this word - I'm paraphrasing to be polite).  I'm not saying "let it become a garbage heap" - but I do think there's a compromise between being an elitist, highly exclusive society and being a help desk - and it's very obvious to me which direction SO seems to be going

Comment: @smartcaveman What does how long either of us have been members of the site have to do with anything?  You're explicitly saying that quality shouldn't be regulated, that we should accept everything, and you're saying that others are wrong for stating that the site has, from the very beginning, existed to have strong quality standards because the sites that came before it that didn't simply didn't work.  You've clearly demonstrated that you don't understand the mission of the site, and why it has been so successful, regardless of how long you've been a member.

Comment: OK, 'elitist, exclusive' again, great:(  Also, 'they are afraid to post on the site' OK! Result!  They will be reduced to actually searching themselves first, instead of just letting the SO drones look up the duplicates for them.

Comment: Also, am I the only one who would be hugely suspicious of an SO/SE query run that returned 1 for every record out of 20?  It's hugely likely to be incorrect, and I would be very wary of posting it.

Comment: @Patrice http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/448556 - the original query was wrong, but this demonstrates my initial intuition is still valid.  It queries the top 100 SO users using the Mike McCaughan's revision and demonstrates that in most cases, the users' respective proportion of reputation (positive contribution) is significantly greater than their proportion of downvotes (negative contribution)

Comment: Such a distribution tensds to be skewed when taken over such a long period.  Today, now, picking up any question from the last 5 minutes is more likely to be downvote-worthy than not.  That was not the case 5 years ago.

Comment: @MartinJames - Given the consistent increase of IT practitioners world-wide, does it not seem problematic for you that we are becoming more closed and the most likely response to new users is to alienate them?  It seems obvious to me that this is a much bigger deterrent than, (for example), experts exchange's sign up fee was when people started preferring SO ...

Comment: It's surely problematic, yes.  Every week, I run out of my 40 downvotes/day earlier and earlier.  If new users continue to post bad questions, then they will get downvoted.  If that results in 'alienation', it's their problem, since nobody can come up with a better solution to the tsunami of terrible trash than 'immediate downvote, move on quickly'.    BTW, still waiting for examples of  questions/answers 'downvoted who either provided legitimate answers or somebody just didn't like what they had to say or how they said it'.

Comment: @eggmatters then you're failing to provide proper feedback.

Comment: Still waiting for examples of questions/answers 'downvoted who either provided legitimate answers or somebody just didn't like what they had to say or how they said it'.

Comment: @eggmatters you seem to have missed the point - I can just keep up with my copypasta on just the C tag.  There is no chance whatsoever of my, (or indeed, anyone). providing mentoring. guidance or advice on that scale.  If you think this is wrong, fine.  We disagree:)  Please feel free to start you own help site and, instead of copypasta into meta questions, I can send them all to you.  Everyone wins!  The posters get mentoring, they are kept off SO and you and I have nothing to complain about any more.  Well, TBH, you will have no time to complain, (or eat, drink, sleep).

Comment: Oh, and if you think that elitist, hostile, unconstructive Martin is not providing quaity help, please feel free to dock my pay.

Comment: "with the addition of so many sister sites, SO is becoming more and more difficult to actually ask a relevant question. I can't get an answer or discussion on anything anymore:" I don't understand why more sister sites make it harder for anyone to ask a relevant question or why you cannot get answers anymore. Maybe the questions you have are not really programming related or of low quality or duplicates?

Comment: Still waiting for examples of questions/answers 'downvoted who either provided legitimate answers or somebody just didn't like what they had to say or how they said it'.  My next post is going to be about tumbleweed and the sighing of windblown sand.

Comment: @eggmatters You are welcome to open a new site for free mentoring. Or just join an existing site. Just accept that this isn't one of those sites, and move where you long to be. The best of luck!

Comment: Great dialog @Deduplicator. I have dared criticize process on a forum provided for just that purpose and am told I'm not welcome here. Go figure.

Comment: @OP: [*Stack Overflow* is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).

Comment: @eggmatters You are quite welcome here, and my apology if my last comment did convey anything different. It's just that you seem to be looking more for an opportunity to mentor people, and this site is not the place for that, it goes against the core aims.

Answer (score -13, accepted):

Well it looks like the jury is still out but we can glean some results from the responses given in the post. From the comments given, and observed trends we can deduce the following:

1. Downvotes and Dismissals are increasing as the number of users is
   increasing. Additionally, many feel that the quality of questions
   asked is decreasing as well. I think this brooks no argument, and
   failed to encapsulate this in my original post.
2. Upvoting is dangerous and can cause more harm than good, while downvoting is healthy and improves the content of this site.

Based on the tenor of comments, it appears that this is ok. *Even if* that comment or answer provided value. I stated that I upvote questions, comments and answers. What I had to qualify, was that I do this if I feel that there was value provided.

I assert that this is the issue at hand and that this nature is doing more harm than good. To put aside the example of poor quality posts, I typically ignore them. The "herd" (and I mean this term neutrally in this case) will decide the quality of a post as providing relevance. I don't feel that is necessarily the value I want to provide and guess what? I and anybody else who uses this site gets to decide that. If I, or any other user are reticent to downvote and then upvote comments that I feel have been unfairly criticized, I get to exercise that right. If this is not ok, then kick me and others like me off.

I argue that rampant downvoting and outright dismissal of posts without giving the OP a chance to edit or fix the post, or provide a justification for a downvote are more harmful than upvoting. If you can't provide feedback on why a question, comment or answer is lacking relevance, then why bother? If it's not worth your time, then why take the time? This post garnered a swath of downvotes in a matter of time that clearly showed folks had not even taken the time to *read* it. Yes, that is harmful.

Also, downvoting, deletions, dismissals etc. carry a negative connotation. Constructive criticism does not. Silence carries less.

I feel like I was accused for attacking an inviolable right of the participants of this forum. That was not my intent. I merely wanted to express an alarming trend that seems to be an ongoing theme.

I don't feel comfortable posting on this site regardless of desire or need. The reputation I have acquired is at the whim of a user base I feel are too quick to criticize without leveraging rationale:

[Receive $.ajax "parsererror" when downloading XLSX file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056585/receive-ajax-parsererror-when-downloading-xlsx-file)

Is an example, This question was asked and answered - provided relevant code and conditions of execution yet was downvoted without any comment.

We shall agree to disagree, and I can take my attitudes elsewhere, I get that, but I urge that in order to grow and change, one must be willing to. The next time you click a thumbs down, leave a constructive comment perhaps. The next time you review a post, give the OP a chance to restructure or move the post to provide relevance.

We ask our users to take time to research and get things right, Shouldn't we do the same before we cast our negative feedback?

Comment: I find it funny that my SO reputation has taken quite a dive in the last 24 hours. Old posts, and old answers, which are completely valid, are getting downvoted. Yet another argument in my case. I am clearly being punished for making this post.

Comment: How'd you self-answer your question 16 minutes after posting it? I thought there was a 2 hour hold on self answers if you didn't write one along with the question.

Comment: @BSMP There was such an influx of negative feedback that I triggered a not-well known feature in Stack Exchange unlocking the self-answering hold. Just kidding. I posted this yesterday. Not sure what timestamp you were seeing.

Comment: @BSMP - question asked `2016-03-10 20:23:20Z`, self-answer at `2016-03-11 17:13:46Z`

Comment: I honestly don't know what you are talking about. This rant makes very little sense. You know that there are poor quality questions here, and that they're increasing in number, yet you want to *stop* moderating them via downvoting and closure? I'm sorry, but that's stupid. Sure, downvotes may carry a negative connotation (although it is not as strong as you and others make it out to be, but that's neither here nor there), but as long as you're agreed that they are poor quality posts, a negative message is the one we want to send. Not only to the poster, but to others who happen along.

Comment: As far as the implication that people are downvoting without reading, well, you have absolutely no evidence for that. I read everything that I downvote very carefully. I happen to be an extremely fast reader, but that doesn't affect my comprehension. I "get things right" before I downvote. This is not an endemic problem. Also, as I'm sure has been explained to you before, closures and downvotes are reversible. If the person who posted the content decides to "get it right" later through editing, that is great, and the downvotes/closure can be reversed. There's a whole process for that.

Comment: But if they don't take the time and/or are unwilling to get it right *before* posting, I don't know why you think we should encourage them. You aren't *required* to post things here. This isn't a mandatory talent show where you have to participate, and we need to cheer everyone on just because they got up on stage. This is a community-moderated Q&A site, where the good content gets pushed to the top and the bad content gets pushed to the bottom. Advocating for anything else is the part that is actively hostile to the purpose of the site. The most alarming trend is the quality decrease.

Comment: @Codygray, pleae re-read the post as well as some of the comments. You may want to revise your assumptions. Thanks for your feedback but I hardly would qualify the above as a rant. And I say nothing about accepting or encouraging poorly written posts. This is dialogue not accusation.

Comment: @WilliamPrice - OK, I must be experiencing some weird bug because I see `asked Aug 17 '15 at 17:45` and `Aug 17 '15 at 18:01` on that ajax question.

Comment: Sorry @BSMP it seemed like you were asking about this meta

Comment: @WilliamPrice - I managed to confuse everyone. No worries.

Comment: By "rant," I was referring to not only this answer, but also the question. It looks even more like a rant and less like "dialogue" when you ask a question making bold claims, and then accept your own answer reiterating the same bold claims.

Answer (score 35):

Sites are created because none of the existing sites cover that topic.  When a new site is created, the questions that would belong there *wouldn't have been on topic anywhere before that site was created* (some exceptions apply, but this is typically true, and if the question was on topic for an older site before the new site is created, it would *still* be on topic there).  So the creation of new sites isn't making it harder to ask questions on any given site.

It's been an important goal of SE that all sites have a strongly defined scope.  That has *always* been the case.  It's not new at all.

> Each site has site specific policies which are stringently adhered to by reviewers.

Yes.  Isn't that great!  We *want* sites to be focused.  It allows people to effectively find questions that they will be interested in, and able to, answer, as easily as possible.

> Site participants readily downvote questions from new users with disparaging comments about why the question doesn't fit the forum.

Assuming the questions *don't* belong on the site, we *want* people to downvote them, to provide feedback to the author, and others, that the question is not a quality question for that site, and providing comments to the author explaining the problems with the question can help them fix it, or at least understand what they did wrong, to avoid making the same mistake in the future.  This is great.  We want this to happen.

> It's getting to the point where I don't want to ask a question about anything anymore because I will get downvoted for not following the rules of engagement.

If you're continually violating the site's rules and posting bad content over and over again then, again, *this is great*.  If you were enthusiastically enjoying harming the site and posting bad content then *it would mean we were doing something wrong*, because it would mean you'd keep on doing it.  Either post *quality* content, or don't post at all; either is fine.

> When I'm researching questions on SO I see many users get downvoted who either provided legitimate answers or somebody just didn't like what they had to say or how they said it.

This is good.  When people are providing answers that a reader thinks is bad, we want them to downvote it.  It's how others can effectively see the quality of the content, particularly if they're not qualified to judge for themselves.

> I upvote a majority of these responses.

This is unfortunate.  You're actively making the site worse, encouraging people for providing bad content, and misleading readers into thinking that the unhelpful content doesn't actually have problems, when it does.  That's a very cruel thing to do.  It's probably the single most harmful behavior you could possibly engage in on the site.

Comment: Did you read the part about upvoting answers where users "provided legitimate answers" C'mon! this is what I'm talking about. You're taking my statements out of context and commenting on them. This is fare more destructive. And it's not all black and white. But the majority if SO sites as well as SO itself are, IMHO too strict with forcing people to adhere to them. Your basically assuming I'm asking a question about Airline Reservations on World Building.

Comment: @eggmatters the way you wrote your post, it DOES sound like "sympathy upvoting". There's a difference between "legitimate answer" and "good answer I'd upvote". So upvoting "legitimate answers" to balance downvotes is actually destructive. Ideally you would not even LOOK at the score of a post to vote on it. If you upvote because it's been wrongly downvoted... it's bad. If you upvote because it's a good post, that's good. The way you phrased your post, it makes it look like you do the former. If you're doing the latter, it's fine.

Comment: @eggmatters That a post "is an answer" doesn't mean it merits upvotes.  You upvote *quality, useful* answers, not just posts that are technically an answer.  You downvote posts that are not useful, even if they are technically answers (sometimes even if they are correct answers, if they aren't *useful* answers).

Comment: Knowing what I know - you can check my profile and elsewhere to get a feel, I can pretty much tell if somebody has provided a valuable answer or not and are downvoted due to whim, attitude etc. If an answer provides no value or is incorrect, I don't upvote it. I'm alarmed at the increasing amount of downvotes everything gets and am dismayed nothing is done to curb it. The all out flame war this post caused kind of states my case.

Comment: @eggmatters with an increase in new posts, it only makes sense for the number of downvotes to increase with it. unfortunately the number of upvotes on low quality posts are also increasing.

Comment: I've waste... spent 10 votes on downvoting correct answers over the last couple days.  Why?  They are all answers to VLQ multi-duped questions, probably seed questions from puppets and voting rings.

Comment: @eggmatters So you're going to refuse to penlight future readers of those posts that those answers are incorrect, by choosing to not downvote an answer that you *know* isn't helpful, thus increasing the odds that that person will at best, waste their time trying an incorrect answer, or worse still, not realize that it has serious problems and use the answer anyway?  That's mean.  Why would you be so cruel?

Comment: @eggmatters Not everyone is qualified to judge the quality of every single answer.  That's why we have voting, so that those that do feel qualified to provide feedback on the quality of the answer can provide useful information to the people that *don't* know how to judge the quality of the answer, and would greatly value seeing that feedback of others.  But thanks for confirming you actively want people to go around using answers that you feel are actively harmful.  You've made it clear that you have no empathy for others, and are intentionally and knowingly harming other people.

Comment: I guess I will donwnvote kneejerk answers where an OP has violated a best practice, in their sample but the answer doesn't answer their question. Stuff like "you should never do X. X is very bad." without explaining why, or not explaining contexts of when it may be appropriate. I will upvote answers that address the OP question and address the best practice violation "BTW, you're query is open to sql injection"